# Update entire item in array - redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update a single object in an array of objects with a redux dispatch, I have tried answers to similar questions however I cannot seem to get it working. What I want to do, is when the action comes in, it should look for an item in the array with the same date as the `action.options.date` it should then replace that item in the array with the new item `actions.options.data[0]` which is the whole item object.

```
const initialState = {
    isFetching: false,
    monthArray: [],
    searchOptions: {
        currentMonth: moment().format('YYYY-MM'),
        leeway: 1
    },
    availabilityOptions: {
        Early: -1,
        Late: -1,
        Day: -1,
        Twilight: -1,
        Night: -1
    }
};
```

```
case UPDATE_DAY_IN_MONTH_ARRAY:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    monthArray: state.monthArray.map(item => {
      if (formatDate(item.date) === formatDate(action.options.date)) {
        return action.options.data[0];
      }
    return item;
  })
});
```

Action code: (Reason for data: data[0] is because an array of objects from mysql is returned)

```
export const updateDayInMonthArray = (date, data) => {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_DAY_IN_MONTH_ARRAY,
        options: {
            date,
            data: data[0]
        }
    }
}
```

Dispatching the action

```
const updateDayInMonthArrayHandler = (date, data) => {
        dispatch(updateDayInMonthArray(date, data));
    }
```

Comment: Could you also paste the code you're using to dispatch the action please?

Comment: @Dan added now!

Comment: your code seems ok, can you add a breakpoint or a console.log in the nested if to check that the the correct comparison is happening (and that the action is correctly dispatched)? 
Maybe there is a problem with the formatDate or the action.options I don't know.

Comment: @GChevass just tried it and the correct comparison is definitely happening, it just doesn't seem to want to update the array

Comment: can you add`updateDayInMonthArray` code to your question?

Comment: @HagaiHarari I've updated that as requested. Just an update aswell I've seemed to get it working however it seems to be using the previous state instead of the new state. e.g if old state was ```{Day: 1, Early: 0}``` and you call it with ```{Day: 0, Early: 0}```, it will show as ```{Day: 1, Early: 0}``` until you do another call which it'll then use ```{Day: 0, Early: 0}```.

Comment: have you try to `...spread` instead `assign`? e.g. `return {...state, monthArray: state.monthArray.map(item => ...}`

Comment: @HagaiHarari just tried that, and still seems to be updating with a previous state :/

Comment: I've just done aswell a ```console.log(monthArray)``` right after I do the call to ```updateDayInMonthArrayHandler()``` and the monthArray doesn't change, does this mean that the dispatch isn't synchronous and needs to be ```await```ed or is this solely due to not updating correctly? Very confused right now :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, and thank you guys for help. Wasn't React or Redux issue, was actually an issue with the node server returning data before checking what was updated.